# What Happens if i create a byte array continuously in a while loop with different size and add read an stream into it?

Tags: java

I want to read an audio file into multiple byte arrays , with different size . And then add into a shared memory.

What will happen if use below code. Does the byte array gets over written. I understand it will create multiple byte array , how do i erase those byte arrays after my code does what it needs to do.

```
int TotalBuffer = 10;
while (TotalBuffer !=0){
    bufferData = new byte[AClipTextFileHandler.BufferSize.get(j)];
    input.read(bufferData);
    Sharedbuffer.put(bufferData);
    i++;
    j++;
    TotalBuffer--;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is Sharedbuffer?

Comment: Thats the buffer allocated to us from other level. we need to put our data into that buffer.

Comment: If you don't keep a reference to the byte arrays they will eventually be garbage collected automatically.

Comment: If you dont know what Sharedbuffer is, how do you expect us to know that then?

Comment: @Antoniossss : I know what is sharedbuffer is . I just don't think it has anything to do with my question.

Comment: That means that your questiong is not clear enought.

Comment: Thank you ..Let me try to make it simple. What happen when we do new byte[somesize] in while loop and read data into it. When i have created so much byte array just to transfer data (put data ) into another buffer , how can i destroy them cause it may eat lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear to my, however if you are asking about that line

```
bufferData = new byte[AClipTextFileHandler.BufferSize.get(j)];
```

than everytime you iterate and create `new byte[]` array, your array object from previous iteration will be garbage collected UNLESS your shared buffer holds reference to it. Anyway, there will be no overwrites etc. since every time there is plain, new, 0 initialized byte array.

Comment: I have almost understood your answere ,one more clairification. Do i need to clear the previously created byte array or it is done automatically?

Comment: It depends what does Sharedbuffer do. Generally, you don't have to clear your arrays to "free memory" or anything else.

Comment: I am writing an android app part in which i am reading an mp3 file part by part into different byte arrays of different size. This is required for specific feature in our project. After reading mp3 file we need to pass the data to another level. So we have been allocated a buffer to which i have named as SharedBuffer . I need to put my byte arrays into this buffer . Hope this might clear idea about sharedbuffer.

Comment: Yes, purpose of that buffer was clear to me from the begining. You did not get my point - why would you like to clear you transient buffer (byte array) ?

Answer (score 1):

No byte array will not be overwritten as because you have used new operator in a while loop body so whenever while loop execute it will create a new object instead of overwriting .

Again for cleaning the memory of an byte array you take a chance by calling Garbage collector explicitly but internally whenever JVM found any unused object in the heap location then only finalize method is called and you write your own implementation to erase the memory of a byte array by assigning the its reference to null.

Note : It not in our hand to deallocate any object memory explicitly. Its all up to the JVM.

Comment: Thank you. That explains a lot